# SQL Server CLR Function Type Mismatch

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlclr

I'm passing a T-SQL type of char(1) into a C# CLR function.

At the C# side I have the type char.

I'm getting the error **"CLR types for parameter ... do not match."**

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AFAIK, `char` SQL Server data type  doesn't have equivalent in the `CLR` for SQL Server in the `System.Data.SqlTypes` namespace, and their native `CLR` equivalents in the Microsoft .NET Framework.

But e.g. `nchar(1)` does - `SqlChars` or `SqlString`  for the CLR data type(SQL Server) and `Char`, `String` or `Char[]` for CLR data type (.NET Framework).

See the MSDN [Mapping CLR Parameter Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131092.aspx) article for more details.